# how can I count the row number in a virtual table that is temporarily created in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, count

I have stored procedure like this

```
create store procedure onetimeprocessing  
as
begin
declare @input_data (id int,title varchar(400),topic varchar(400))
insert into @input_data
select id,title,topic from dB
```

I just want to count number of records in the virtual table @input_data

How should I get the count.Please help me 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input_data`??

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) from @input_data
```

or after the insert

```
select @@rowcount
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have this?

```
create store procedure onetimeprocessing  
as
begin
select COUNT(*) as TheCount from dB
```

Edit

I'm having difficulty understanding why other folk would suggest to load `@inputdata` first, then count from that. or return an extra result set with `@@ROWCOUNT`...

Answer (score 1):

Its available in [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

```
declare @input_data table (id int,title varchar(400),topic varchar(400))
insert into @input_data select ....

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```